# How to query Apache Ignite cache using some SQL query tool?

Tags: sql, console-application, ignite

Is there explanation and step by step example on how to set JDBC/ODBC with some comercial or open source tool (e.g. datagrip, sql-workbench or some other sql-console), and query Ignite cache with regular SQL query?

p.s. Looking for external client example, not a java code to query it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/sql-tooling

It uses DBeaver as an example, but the same can be applied to other tools as well.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if is possible to run SQL query against Ignite cache using Python? (and if it is - how to setup)

Comment: You can use ODBC for this: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/odbc-driver